# How can I view updates without installing them in CentOS

Tags: centos, package-management

How can I view updates/upgrades for both the kernel and packages in CentOS without installing them? I know there's a way to do it in Ubuntu, I would like to know how to do it in CentOS.

Answer (score 3):

```
yum check-update
```

alternatively you can use

```
yum --security check-update
```

Which just checks for security updates.